# Spatial Analysis issues

Tags: qgis, postgis, spatial-analyst

I have this layers:

This one is the main layer (all of them are small polygons)
[image]

And this buffers
[image]

I need to cover all (or most part) of the pink polygons.
So I decided to make centroids (Only to keep the data), and the results are this
[image]

Then I made buffers of the centroids (same length of the orange), later the difference operation between both and I have this
[image]

So the problem is what's next? I made one result but literally deleting one by one the buffers that I think are useless and the result is this
[image]

I'm looking to make something like that but I don't know maybe a better way to do it (I mean nothing manually). I've tried some operations (like intersections, differences, symmetric differences, etc)but nothing seems to work really well. I use the base QGIS just for having better images, then I need to make all of this process on PostGIS so I don't use plugins or something extra.

Comment: Can you better clarify the end goal? When you say you delete the buffers that are 'useless' what does that mean exactly? Why are you removing those and what is the end goal?

Comment: The end goal is getting something like the final photo where the buffer of the centroids covers most part of the pink polygons but only with the necessary buffers not too many.
And for I say useless because there are too many and doesn't look good, in fact, all of them covers the polygons but it's like there is too much redundancy.

Comment: hexagonal polygons would fit better https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82362/what-are-the-benefits-of-hexagonal-sampling-polygons

Comment: Are you trying to generate a grid of circles that cover your pink polygons?

Comment: @Tigerwoulds yes, that could work too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate all your points > remove points that are within a set distance of each other > generate your buffers.

You may have to play around with the distance to get the results you are looking for.

If you think Hexagons would work, give this workflow a try: http://jonathansoma.com/lede/foundations-2018/qgis/grid/

Comment: Helps a lot, give me an idea. Thanks

Comment: @Jeff_Barahona sounds good. If you think the answer is sufficient, please mark it as accepted.